SAR and ISAR sampling time
I'm seeking insight into the typical values of sampling times or refresh rates in radar systems. Specifically, I want to understand the time interval a radar operator must wait to receive new output from a radar system. I'm particularly interested in the special cases of Synthetic Aperture Radars (SARs) and Inverse Synthetic Aperture Radars (ISARs).
Currently, I'm delving into some literature on SARs and ISARs, but they haven't mentioned sampling time, sampling interval, or refresh frequency explicitly. The closest information I've come across, although I suspect it might not be directly related, is the pulse repetition period. This parameter denotes the time interval between two consecutive pulses. Therefore, I presume the sampling time cannot be shorter than this period. However, given that some signal processing is conducted on the raw data collected by these systems, I suspect the sampling time is typically longer than the pulse repetition period.
At present, I estimate the typical values of sampling time to fall within the range of [1s, 1ms]. My upper bound is in the order of seconds because I consider radars with mechanically rotating antennas, where a complete revolution typically takes several seconds. I believe radars that aren't mechanically steered can have shorter sampling times. My lower bound is based on the values I've found for the pulse repetition frequencies of SARs and ISARs.
Unfortunately, I'm completely new to this topic, so I would greatly appreciate assistance from someone more experienced than myself.

ISAR has been around a long time (at least back to the 1980's.) Phased arrays can and do use software to pulse targets of interest rather than sweep. So there will be ongoing sweeps but also, as targets are selected by an operator, those targets can be given special attention (much more frequent pulses.) The sweeps could be disabled entirely and only targets tracked, or no targets and only sweeps. And any combination of same with any amount of "emphasis" given to any target. Targets can even be painted to get more detail, if needed. I'm not sure what the question is, then.

Thank you for your response. Allow me to clarify my question. Suppose we aim to track the motion of an airplane from t=0 seconds to t=60 seconds. We possess a radar capable of detecting the airplane's position every T seconds. My question is: "Depending on the type of radar and its mode of operation, what are reasonable values for T?"

Processor and software dependent. Painting takes time. But with it, you can figure out whether or not it is 2-engine, 4-engine, rough body size and perhaps orientation, etc. Often can identify the specific craft make. (Depending on how far out.) You should be able to look this all up. On the order of tens of kHz rates, or better. Look up ISAR with keywords like "high resolution", "interferometric", and "iterative phase autofocus" for example. Lots of info. It's been decades for me. New and better stuff, faster processing, etc. I'm just not up to speed.

@matteogost - Tracking the motion of an airplane from t=0 to t=60 seconds, as you asked in your comment, is not the function of a SAR, or ISAR radar system.  Other types of radars, specifically pulse doppler systems, do that.

@matteogost This is a pretty deep dive. The ADC sampling frequency and the pulse-repetition interval (PRI) have some fundamental considerations concerning the bandwidth of the waveform, desired unambiguous range and Doppler spans, and measurement update rate. These are important to any radar system and you should look into these before you try to apply them to SAR/ISAR. These impose additional requirements on these to form a good image, and are dependent on the platform that is being used. This isn't even considering how the data is collected and what imaging method is being used.

@Envidia - I agree with your comment.  But I don't think OP was talking about ADC sampling rate (which is directly related to the IBW of the signal, or waveform).  OP mention sampling times of 1 ms to 1 s, which wold be 1 kHz to 1 Hz.

@SteveSh Yeah that's probably true. I mentioned it because the OP makes a distinction between the PRI and some "other" sampling time later in reference to raw data.

@Envidia - Re-reading OP's post, I think what he means by sample time/period I would call re-visit time.  That is, the time it takes for the radar beam to get back to a target, or point of interest.

I understand that my question is ill-posed. Let me provide more details about what I'm trying to do. I'm attempting to develop a Kalman filter to estimate the position, attitude, and shape of an airplane. This filter recursively processes the measurements generated by a sensor, which is assumed to produce a new measurement every T seconds. I understand that air surveillance is typically conducted using ground-based ISAR sensors. Therefore, I'm trying to determine reasonable values of T for my specific application of Kalman filtering. Thank you for your help; I'm learning a lot from you.

OK.  This seems to be more in the realm of signal processing than EE.  That is, you seem to be asking about algorithms rather than hardware.  I would re-post to the Signal Processing SE.
